# Cannot upload big zip files using drop-zone in CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to upload zip file using drop zone. Uploading just fine with small size zip files. However, for zip more than 5MB cannot upload. Somehow the uploading process stuck at 100% and remain there until page refresh manually.

**You can see here:**

[image: here]

after dragging the file, at 100% it getting stuck and error come up in the console.

**Error:**

[image: here]

HTML

```
<?php $exts = str_replace('"', '', $this->product_settings->digital_allowed_file_extensions);
$exts = str_replace(',', ", ", $exts);
$exts = strtoupper($exts); ?>
<div class="form-box">
    <div class="form-box-head">
        <h4 class="title">
            <?php echo trans('digital_files'); ?>
            <small><?php echo trans("allowed_file_extensions"); ?>:&nbsp;<strong class="font-500"><?php echo $exts; ?></strong></small>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="form-box-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div id="digital_files_upload_result" class="row-custom">
                    <?php $this->load->view('dashboard/product/_digital_files_upload_response'); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="error-message error-message-file-upload"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- File item template -->
<script type="text/html" id="files-template-digital-files">
    <li class="media">
        <div class="media-body">
            <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</script>
```

**JS**: library that I'm using here: https://github.com/danielm/uploader

```
<script>
    $('#drag-and-drop-zone-digital-files').dmUploader({
        url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>upload-digital-files-post',
        queue: true,
        extFilter: [<?php echo $this->product_settings->digital_allowed_file_extensions;?>],
        multiple: false,
        extraData: function (id) {
            return {
                "product_id": <?php echo $product->id; ?>,
                "<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>": $.cookie(csfr_cookie_name)
            };
        },
        onDragEnter: function () {
            this.addClass('active');
        },
        onDragLeave: function () {
            this.removeClass('active');
        },
        onNewFile: function (id, file) {
            ui_multi_add_file(id, file, "digital-files");
        },
        onBeforeUpload: function (id) {
            ui_multi_update_file_progress(id, 0, '', true);
            ui_multi_update_file_status(id, 'uploading', 'Uploading...');
        },
        onUploadProgress: function (id, percent) {
            ui_multi_update_file_progress(id, percent);
        },
        onUploadSuccess: function (id, data) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
            if (obj.result == 1) {
                document.getElementById("digital_files_upload_result").innerHTML = obj.html_content;
            }
        },
        onFileExtError: function (file) {
            $(".error-message-file-upload").html("<?php echo trans('invalid_file_type'); ?>");
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(".error-message-file-upload").empty();
            }, 4000);
        },
    });
    $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
        $('#drag-and-drop-zone-digital-files').dmUploader({
            url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>upload-digital-files-post',
            queue: true,
            extFilter: [<?php echo $this->product_settings->digital_allowed_file_extensions;?>],
            multiple: false,
            extraData: function (id) {
                return {
                    "product_id": <?php echo $product->id; ?>,
                    "<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>": $.cookie(csfr_cookie_name)
                };
            },
            onDragEnter: function () {
                this.addClass('active');
            },
            onDragLeave: function () {
                this.removeClass('active');
            },
            onNewFile: function (id, file) {
                ui_multi_add_file(id, file, "digital-files");
            },
            onBeforeUpload: function (id) {
                ui_multi_update_file_progress(id, 0, '', true);
                ui_multi_update_file_status(id, 'uploading', 'Uploading...');
            },
            onUploadProgress: function (id, percent) {
                ui_multi_update_file_progress(id, percent);
            },
            onUploadSuccess: function (id, data) {
                var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                if (obj.result == 1) {
                    document.getElementById("digital_files_upload_result").innerHTML = obj.html_content;
                }
            },
            onFileExtError: function (file) {
                $(".error-message-file-upload").html("<?php echo trans('invalid_file_type'); ?>");
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $(".error-message-file-upload").empty();
                }, 4000);
            },
        });
    });
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
  //upload digital files
    public function upload_digital_files($product_id)
    {
        if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {
            if (empty($_FILES['file']['name'])) {
                exit();
            }
        }
        $product = $this->product_model->get_product_by_id($product_id);
        if (!empty($product)) {
            $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $file_name = str_slug($this->general_settings->application_name) . "-digital-file-" . $product->id . uniqid() . "." . $ext;
            $this->load->model('upload_model');
            if ($this->upload_model->digital_file_upload('file', $file_name)) {
                $data = array(
                    'product_id' => $product_id,
                    'user_id' => user()->id,
                    'file_name' => $file_name,
                    'storage' => 'local',
                    'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                );
                @$this->db->close();
                @$this->db->initialize();
                $this->db->insert('digital_files', $data);
            }
        }
    }

//digital file upload
    public function digital_file_upload($input_name, $file_name)
    {
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/digital-files/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = '*';
        $config['file_name'] = $file_name;
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ($this->upload->do_upload($input_name)) {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            if (isset($data['upload_data']['full_path'])) {
                return true;
            }
            return null;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to this issue is here.
I changed the server limits to this way and it work well now.

```
memory_limit = 250M //The maximum amount of memory in bytes a script is allowed to allocate.
max_input_time = 600 //The maximum time in seconds a script is allowed to parse input data.
max_execution_time = 600 //The maximum time in seconds a script is allowed to run before it is terminated.

post_max_size = 200M //The maximum size in bytes of data that can be posted with the POST method. Typically, should be larger than upload_max_filesize and smaller than memory_limit.
upload_max_filesize = 100M //The maximum size in bytes of an uploaded file.
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all your code's error is not clear. You can print the variable data before calling JSON.parse as follows so it shows the original error.

```
onUploadSuccess: function (id, data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
```

I think you are not set the content-type header to JSON in Codeigniter before returning the results.

Just add the following code in the PHP file and try

```
$this->response->setContentType('Content-Type: application/json');
```

And return responses after successful file upload

```
return json_encode(['status'=>'ok','path'=>'file-path']);
```

If it will not work then first try the demo code given in this package.
https://github.com/danielm/uploader/tree/master/demo